# CakePHP 3.x create Form templates

Tags: php, forms, templates, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I would like to create several different form templates. The CakePHP documentation is an example of how to place a template in the app_form.php file. I did it. Works, but how to do it to have several different templates? The one that I created overwrites all forms in the application. My template:

```
    return [
        'formStart' => '<form class="form-horizontal" {{attrs}}>',

        'legend' => '<legend>{{text}}</legend>',
        'inputContainerError' => '<div class="input {{class}} {{type}}{{required}} error">{{content}}{{error}}</div>',
        'inputContainer'=>'<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">{{legend}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">{{content}}</div></div>',
        'input'=>'<input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control input-small" {{attrs}} />',
        'submitContainer'=>'<div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            {{content}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>',
        'select' => '<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{legend}}</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8"><select class="form-control input medium" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div></div>',
        'label' => '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}{{label}}</label>',

];
```

My random form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create()?>
<?= $this->Form->control("domyslny",['type'=>'text','label'=>"dupa"])?>
<?= $this->Form->select("gs_category_id",$listGsMenu,['id'=>'gs_category_id','label'=>"GS category"]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->select("tim_category_id",$listTimMenu,['id'=>'tim_category_id']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit(__d('Categories','Submit'),['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?>
<?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create many different form templates, by reload helper in Your controller:

```
// In a View class
$this->loadHelper('Form', [
    'templates' => 'app_form', // Load app_form.php
]);
```

Comment: Yes, I did it and overwrites all forms in the application in this way. But how do you define more than one template for different forms?

Comment: How load more form templates for one view and how use i all?